# Android - achartengine bar chart issues

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I use achartengine to draw my chart in an android application and have 2 issues with bar chart.

1: values at top bar doesn't align center

2: width of bar too small when just 1 bar in chart

[image]

[image]

Here my code for setting chart

```
    GraphicalView mChart;
    // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("\n" + note);
    // Adding data to Series
    // Arraylist<String> althongtin include input data (some numbers character, eg: {125, 4356, 50000})
    for(int i=0;i<althongtin.size();i++){
        incomeSeries.add(i, Double.parseDouble(althongtin.get(i)));
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
    XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    incomeRenderer.setColor(color);
    incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
    incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle(ten);
    multiRenderer.setXTitle(cotx);
    multiRenderer.setYTitle(coty);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
    multiRenderer.setBarWidth(50);

    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(max + (max/10));
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(althongtin.size() + 1);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
    multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0,255,255,255));
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);

    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);

    String[] types = new String[] {BarChart.TYPE};

    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, types);

    multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    chartLayout.addView(mChart);
```

Thanks.

Updated: the second issue is fixed by upgrade to achartengine 1.2.0. Thank yoou, Dan.

Comment: Your above code is fine .What about your dataset code and GraphicalView?

Comment: @UnokenMouny hi, may I know how did u set the spacing between the bars? it didnt work for me when I used "   multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);" Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue, you may want to upgrade to the 1.2.0 nightly build.

For the second one, there is: `renderer.setBarWidth(widthInPixels);` as this is the solutions to set the bar width when there is one single item in the series.

Comment: =)) oh man....i upgrade to the 1.2.0 and the second issue is fixed.....but the 1st one still get no change...awww

Comment: @dan hey i faced the same issue for the alin center? hv u got the solution or not? another is i can not change the color only Bar value not bar chart? we need black color of bar value with align center.plz help

Answer (score 0):

why not using `ChartFactory.getBarChartView` instead of `ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartIntent` ?

I think it will fix ur problem .

Comment: Nothing changed, i still get same issues